# tag + tag-version, or just tag-version?

Tags: discussion, tags

Should questions about a specific version of something have both the general tag of it and the version tag, or just the version tag? For example: If I'm asking "How do the Home and Professional versions of Windows XP differ?", do I tag it [[windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows)]+[[windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp)], or just [[windows-xp](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-xp)]?

What about regular questions about Windows, i.e. If I have a certain version of Windows, but my question isn't specifically about that version, for example: "I need sound editing software for Windows. I'm on Windows XP.". On Mac OSX: "I can't get printing working. I'm on OSX." Do I tag it [[mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mac)] and [[osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx)], or just [[osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/osx)]?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [General Tag vs. Version Tag, and Multiple Version Tags](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/9198/general-tag-vs-version-tag-and-multiple-version-tags)

Answer (score 9):

If the question is about a specific version, then it should be just the version.

Comment: Not in all cases; we (you) recently unified the tags [tag:virtual-pc] (the general tag) and [tag:windows-virtual-pc] (the version-specific tag) into a single tag.

Answer (score 7):

I always remove the "windows" tag if a question is tagged with "windows" AND "windows-xp". "windows-xp" already makes clear it's about windows. Otherwise, if there's a question about Windows XP Home, you should tag it as. "windows" + "windows-xp" + "windows-xp-home" Which causes for two redundant tags in my opinion.

if a question is not about a specific version, I'd tag it as "windows" only.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac OS X it's a bit different:

`[mac]` refers to the hardware
`[osx]` refers to all versions of Mac OS X in general
`[osx-snow-leopard]` and such specify a specific version.

I've put more on the tag info pages: [Mac](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=mac&sort=info&pagesize=50) and [osx](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=osx&sort=info&pagesize=50)