# Handling general plus specific tags in a question

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup-request

In many cases, questions will be tagged with both a specific tag and a general tag.  For example, [network-interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-interface) and [interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interface) on a question dealing with network interfacing.  Both tags are undefined.  [network-interface] is unambiguous but [interface] covers a lot more territory.  If all network interface questions use only the [network-interface] tag, it would reduce the diversity of meaning under the [network] tag.  It could be that the remaining meanings are sufficiently similar that grouping them under an umbrella tag is fine.

This post, [tag-tag-version-or-just-tag-version](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/1261/tag-tag-version-or-just-tag-version), indicates that as a general rule, the generic tag should be removed if a specific tag is appropriate.  When I see examples, should I just go ahead and fix the tag or is this something that should be posted here for review?

Answer (score 2):

[interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interface) is a bad example, because it's a horrible tag. In this specific case, [interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interface) should just be removed.

Instead of giving a rule, let me give a couple of examples. I don't think there really is a good rule anyway…

1. [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) [port-forwarding](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/port-forwarding)
   Probably fine as it is. Assume people have tags starred, would someone who starred [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) like to see this question? If it's about port forwarding, he probably would.
2. [windows](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows) [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7)
   Should be tagged just [windows-7](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-7), *especially* since "windows" is a substring of "windows-7".
3. [network](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network) [interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/interface) [network-interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-interface)
   A personal favorite of mine, should only be tagged [network-interface](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/network-interface).
4. [networking](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/networking) [internet](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet) [browser](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/browser) [internet-explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) [internet-explorer-11](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-11)
   Should very likely only be tagged [internet-explorer-11](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer-11).

Comment: That sounds like the answer should be "opinion-based".  :-)  In terms of the last sentence of the question, is the appropriate protocol "opinion-based" (just apply personal judgement), or should proposed "mass" tag changes be posted here for review?

Comment: @fixer1234: Use your best judgement ;) If a certain combination is used a lot, it might need to be discussed here, but you certainly don't have to bring every edit to everyone's attention.

Comment: "mass" tag changes = used a lot.

Comment: And the last one could probably add an OS tag as well to get more (relevant) views.